# How do I create a SearchBar on a TableView with sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, searchbar

I need a search bar for my table view, but I'm a beginner and I'm cracking my head to do it.

In my table view I have a couple of sections. Each section is populated with items that contains a name and a date. I want the user to be able to make a research through the name.

One more thing: in order to make it easier and more organized, I created an enum and would like to use it to name the sections.

I've made an example to show how far I've reached:

```
class Cinema: UITableViewController {

// MARK: - Properties

var movie:[(type: Genre, data:[Movies])] = []

//MARK: - Super Methods
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    movie = [

        (Genre.Action, [

            Movies (name: "Matrix", year: "1999", description: "A computer hacker learns from mysterious rebels about the true nature of his reality and his role in the war against its controllers."),

            Movies (name: "Gladiator", year: "2000", description: "When a Roman general is betrayed and his family murdered by an emperor's corrupt son, he comes to Rome as a gladiator to seek revenge."),

            Movies (name: "Saving Private Ryan", year: "1998", description: "Following the Normandy Landings, a group of U.S. soldiers go behind enemy lines to retrieve a paratrooper whose brothers have been killed in action.")
            ]),

        (Genre.Drama, [

            Movies (name: "Good Will Hunting", year: "1997", description: "Will Hunting, a janitor at M.I.T., has a gift for mathematics, but needs help from a psychologist to find direction in his life."),

            Movies (name: "Schindler's List", year: "1993", description: "In Poland during World War II, Oskar Schindler gradually becomes concerned for his Jewish workforce after witnessing their persecution by the Nazis.")
            ]),

        (Genre.Comedy, [

            Movies (name: "Monty Python and the Holy Grail", year: "1975", description: "King Arthur and his knights embark on a low-budget search for the Grail, encountering many, very silly obstacles."),

            Movies (name: "Hangover", year: "2009", description: "Three buddies wake up from a bachelor party in Las Vegas, with no memory of the previous night and the bachelor missing. They make their way around the city in order to find their friend before his wedding.")

            ])
    ]


}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return movie.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return movie[section].data.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ADTableViewCell

    cell.title.text = movie[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row].name
    cell.year.text = movie[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row].year

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 {
        return "Action"
    } else if section == 1 {
        return "Drama"
    } else {
        return "Comedy"
    }
}
```

}

P.S: When the user clicks the line he chose, he will be sent to an UIViewController that will show the name, year and description. I didn't create a prepareForSegue here in this example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomment you to follow this [Link](http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/01/08/ios-quick-tip-filtering-a-uitableview-with-a-search-bar/)

I have used it in my project and was really easy to implement and maintain.  You would have to manage two array results:

> **1. Matched with search text**
>
> **2. Without any search text**
>
> ***Reload the table section and rows overtime you type a text.***

Let me know if you face any problem implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to have an array of movies and filtered movies. The datasource should be the filtered movies which by default would be the movies. When searching for a field with your search field, you should filter your array of movies following your criteria depending on the text on the search field. Then, you should reload the data of the tableview and your search items only should appear. Depending on how you want to implement it, could be done each time you change your textfield or when it stops editing or when it returns.

```
var filteredMovie:[(type: Genre, data:[Movies])] = []

func yourTextfieldDelegate(textField: Textfield) {
    if textField.text.characters.count == 0{
        self.filteredMovie = self.movie
    }
    else{
        // for example, filter by name
        self.filteredMovie = movie.filter($0.data.name.lowercase.contains(textfield.text.lowercase))
        self.tableViewRef.reloadData()
    }

}
```

ps: you are missing an outlet for your tableView. I called it tableViewRef.